# Help finding integral: $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1 + x + x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Could someone help me with finding this integral

$$\int  \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1 + x + x^2}}$$

or give a hint on how to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+1%2F%28x+sqrt%281%2Bx%2Bx^2%29%29) will show you steps for the solution if you click on "Show Steps", but one might hope that there would be an easier way than what it shows...

Comment: yep, I know but as you said I was hoping for a batter solution and seems like i got it :), thanks Américo Tavares

Comment: Once again: "Solving" is the wrong word.  One solves equations; one solves problems.  One _evaluates_ expressions.

Comment: He's created a new problem in that he doesn't know how to evaluate this integral, and is asking for help in solving that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the integrand is a quadratic irrational function of the type $R(x,\sqrt{1+x+x^{2}})$, you may use the [Euler substitution](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Euler_substitutions) $\sqrt{1+x+x^{2}}=x+t$. You get

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1+x+x^{2}}} &=&\int \frac{2}{t^{2}-1}\,dt \\
&=&-2\operatorname{arctanh}t+C \\
&=&-2\operatorname{arctanh}\left( \sqrt{1+x+x^{2}}-x\right)+C. 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: I have just solved this on paper step by step, and I wonder shouldn't it be $ln\frac{x - a}{x + a}$ instead of arctg as it's (t^2 - 1) not plus 1

Comment: @Dave: You can rewrite the integral by using the identity

$\operatorname{arctanh}t=\frac{1}{2}\ln \left( t+1\right) -\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(
1-t\right) .$

Answer (score 7):

Make the substitution $x = \frac{1}{t}$ and this reduces to finding

$$\int \frac{\text{d}t}{\sqrt{t^2 + t + 1}}$$

which can easily be reduced to finding the standard integral:

$$ \int \frac{\text{d}z}{\sqrt{z^2 + 1}} = \sinh^{-1}(z) + C$$

This substitution can be used for finding

$$\int \frac{\text{d}x}{x\sqrt{P(x)}}$$

where $P(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial in $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}dx=\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}}dx$.$\;\;$  Now let $x+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan\theta$, $dx=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sec^{2}\theta d\theta$

to get $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan\theta-\frac{1}{2})(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sec\theta)}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sec^{2}\theta d\theta=\int\frac{\sec\theta}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan\theta-\frac{1}{2}}d\theta=\int\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin\theta-\frac{1}{2}\cos\theta}d\theta$

$\;\;=\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{-\cos(\theta+\frac{\pi}{3})}d\theta=-\int\sec\big(\theta+\frac{\pi}{3}\big)d\theta=-\ln\left|\sec\big(\theta+\frac{\pi}{3}\big)+\tan\big(\theta+\frac{\pi}{3}\big)\right|+C$

$\;\;=-\displaystyle\ln\left|\frac{-2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}{\sqrt{3}x}-\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{3}x}\right|+C=-\ln\left|\frac{2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x+2}{\sqrt{3}x}\right|+C$

$\;\;\displaystyle=\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x+2}\right|+C=\ln|x|-\ln\left(2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+x+2\right)+C$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The substitution $x = \frac{1}{t}$ works. But check for the  minus sign.

It does reduce to integral of $\frac{-dt}{\sqrt{t^2+t+1}}$, which can be reduced further to integral of $\frac{-dz}{z^2 + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}}$

Regards,
Prakash

Answer (score 0):

Letting $y=\frac{1}{x}$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d x}{x\sqrt{1+x+x^2}} & =\int \frac{1}{\frac{1}{y} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{y^2}}} \frac{d y}{-y^2} \\
& =-\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+y+1}} d y \\
& =-\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}} d y \\
& =-\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{y+\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)+C \\
&=-\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2+x}{\sqrt{3} x}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$